# How to increase speed of code using data structures rather than for-next loops?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have already resolved several others using `Application.Index` with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` and reduced time to perform from about 7-8 seconds to milliseconds. But I feel there is still room for improvement.

Should I use an array with `Index` and `Match`?

I was also told to use `Scripting.Dictionary`, but I am looking for someone who can demonstrate how to do it the right away in this scenario. Because in my head I have to populate the dictionary with a loop before I can even use that, so wont it be similar in terms of speed?

```
'Production Quantity for Dashboard
For i = 2 To Total_rows_Prod
    For j = 2 To Total_rows_Dash
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(i, 5) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 1) Then
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 4) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 4) + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(i, 31) / ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(i, 4)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

After doing some bottleneck testing as shown below (run time of code is shown at row 10):
[image]

However, when using `Index` and `Match` while only using 1 `for-next` loop as shown in the code below:

```
'Production Quantity for Dashboard
For i = 2 To Total_rows_Prod
    m = Application.Match(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(i, 5), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A:A"), 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(i, 5), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A:A"), 0), 4) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(i, 5), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A:A"), 0), 4) + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(i, 31) / ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(i, 4)
    End If
Next i
```

The run time would be negligible as shown below (still at row 10):

[image]

The final time I was able to make everything run with `Index` and `Match` replacements was 2 seconds:

[image]

But on a slower netbook running a Pentium Atom processor, it takes 26 seconds to perform the same code. So I am wondering if there is way to bring down that 26 seconds.

Any improvements that would make the time to perform optimally minimized would be great. Considering dictionaries, but I have no idea how to apply them given there is a `Key` and `Value` parameter for `.Add` and in my head it requires 2 `for-next` loops to do the same thing?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd assume `Index` and `Match` are the best way to approach this. Store the relevant keys from the sheet you want to match in a `Scripting.Dictionary`, then use `.Exists` as you loop through the other one.  Trying to write VBA like it's an Excel function is typically not the way to get the best performance.

Comment: @Comintern thanks I just did it based on my testing and it was the only way I knew how to do

Comment: @Comintern I am wondering though if I populate `Scripting.Dictionary` with the `keys` don't I have to run a `for-next` loop to do so? Then i'll need to run another `for-next` loop to check the dictionary if it `.Exists`? While the `Index` and `Match` should only need a single `for-next` loop to do the whole thing. In terms of speed which is faster?

Comment: You still need to run a for-next loop, but they're not nested anymore. What you'd be doing is leveraging the fact that a `Dictionary` does hashed lookup instead of traversing the entire collection.  Take a look at [this answer over on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/203214/36565) to get a better idea of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general most time consuming part of VBA code is to read and write values from / to worksheets. You should reduce that as much as you can.

Easiest way to reduce such operations is to read your input data into arrays, manipulate it as you need, then write back the output.
You can read more about that e.g. here: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Your updated code would look something like this:

```
Dim arr_prodQty5 As Variant
Dim arr_DashBoard1 As Variant
Dim arr_DashBoard4 As Variant
Dim arr_prodQty31 As Variant
Dim arr_prodQty4 As Variant

arr_prodQty5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(Total_rows_Prod, 5))
arr_prodQty4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(Total_rows_Prod, 4))
arr_prodQty31 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(Total_rows_Prod, 5))
arr_DashBoard1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(total_rows_dash, 1))
arr_DashBoard4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(total_rows_dash, 4))

For i = 2 To Total_rows_Prod
    For j = 2 To total_rows_dash
        If arr_prodQty5(i, 1) = arr_DashBoard1(j, 1) Then
           arr_DashBoard4(j, 1) = arr_DashBoard4(j, 1) + arr_prodQty31(i, 1) / arr_prodQty4(i, 1)
        End If
    Next j
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(total_rows_dash, 4)) = arr_DashBoard4
```

*(I don't have your data, so I couldn't check whether it actually works, most probably you'll need to make some bug fix before running it)*

Using dictionary instead of arrays is just a more sophisticated way to achieve the same result.